# Why does the auto keyword allow creating instances of privately declared inner-classes or inner-structs?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, struct, inner-classes

I found something weird in C++ that I don't understand why it's happening.

I have an inner class with a private struct definition, it looks like this:

```
#include <string>
class A {
private:
    class B {
    private:
        struct C {
            int lol;
            std::string ok;
        };
    public:
        B() {}
        C* makething();
    };
public:
    A() {}
    void dostuff();
};
```

`C* makething();` simply returns a new struct C, like this:

```
A::B::C* A::B::makething()
{
    C* x = new C;
    return x;
}
```

So now if the implementation for `void dostuff();` is like this:

```
void A::dostuff()
{
    B x = B();
    B::C* thing = x.makething(); // compile error
    thing->lol = 42;
    thing->ok = "some words";
    std::cout << thing->lol << " " << thing->ok;
}
```

It gives me the error: `C2248 'A::B::C': cannot access private struct declared in class 'A::B'` This was expected, because struct C is declared as private within class B.

However, if I change the line `B::C* thing = x.makething();` to `auto thing = x.makething();`, it will compile and no longer gives me the error that struct C is private, and then I can modify the struct's values like I did in the `makething()` function.

Why is this happening? Why does the `auto` keyword allow me to create instances of privately declared structs or classes?

Edit: I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 as the compiler.

Edit 2: Didn't realize this was a duplicate, couldn't find anything when I was searching for an answer. Thanks for the responses though everyone, it makes sense now.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, I'd mention the compiler you're using, along with the version number.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015. I added that as an edit to the original post.

Comment: Yeah, I saw, good. There isn't much I can tell you about this other than it seems wrong, better C++ programmers will pipe in though!

Comment: Not a bug. Access control in C++ applies to *names*, not the thingies ("entities") they refer to.

Comment: Basically, `private` only hides the *name* of the type. You can still deduce it (you could also, for example, pass it as argument to a function template).

Comment: @Quentin: Whaaat? Really? But that's ridiculous, if you can deduce the name, why can't you use the name?

Comment: @einpoklum The important part is that a type can have many names, and those names may be in different scopes. Have a look at chill's answer in the dupe.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: My logic says that if you have a public method returning `B::C*`, I need to be able to instantiate a `B::C*`. Essentially I expect this to be similar to a forward declaration.

Comment: @einpoklum I was a bit unclear : you can deduce the *type*, not its name.